# Setting SharedPreference within Fragments as Tabs

Tags: android-fragments, tabs, sharedpreferences

I'm having problems with what I thought was a simple use of SharedPreferences!

Aim: I've a ActionBar/Tab application with a MainActivity and 4 Tabs as swipe Fragments. I want the App to remember the last user selected Tab, so that on the next start of the App, it defaults to that Tab.

Code in each Fragment (in the `onCreateView` method):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit().putInt("tabPref", 0);
editor.apply();
```

where the `"tabPref", 0` is the name of the pref and number of the Tab (0-3).

In the MainActivity, I'm using the following to read the preference and set the default tab on starting the App (in onCreate):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Integer tabPref = prefs.getInt("tabPref", 99);
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tabPref, false);
```

However, I'm getting some really weird preferences being set, that don't conform to the selection of the tab (e.g. Tab 4 doesn't even set the preference, and Tabs 1-3 randomly set Integers 0, 1, 2 or 3 - I'm using System.Outs to see what's happening).

Am I missing something fundamental regarding the life cycle of the fragments that isn't properly setting the SharedPreference?

Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I needed to set the SharedPreferences in the OnPageChangeListener class within MainActivity, not in the Fragments (doh!).

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit().putInt("tabPref", position);
            editor.apply();
        }
});
```